# How to edit a message with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, fivem

What I want: 
I want to make this interval edit the message every minute to update the server stats for my fivem server, all though I don't know how to edit the message. I've tried multiple ways, I am wondering if I declared `channelStat` incorrectly or the method to edit a message with `discord.js` is different than what I am trying.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**I've tried the `.edit()` function, which is in the code sample**

Code:

```js
var serverStats = setInterval(function () {
    const channelStat = client.channels.cache.get('902678733977157632').messages.fetch('902682557789908992')
    Gamedig.query({
        type: 'fivem',
        host: config.ipabs,
        port: config.port
    }).then((state) => {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Logic RP Stats:')
            .setImage('https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/PaPGVPWBJVWcsboWGg9IWOfE0U0QSj1sb3UEwYIHYcA/https/images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/zcWeRc4OUGdU4UKejuGPzrBt2CvqZY8iIqPZtcrUc84/https/images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/QyWWFfOXuBL0VfdsZNJJdwoLQKQcvmpXo9IHRZoDM6U/https/cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/reaction_roles/images/873023096611799080/911344681e6437aff9cc5e8a6660412e8733a43cde7dc38d01649a557a5e46d8.gif')
            .addFields(
                {
                    name: "Status:",
                    value: `Online`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: "Queue:",
                    value: `${state}`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: "IP:",
                    value: `${state.connect}`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: "Next Restart:",
                    value: `12:00 PM EST`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: "Players:",
                    value: `${state.raw.clients}/${state.maxplayers}`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: "Ping:",
                    value: `${state.ping}`,
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    name: "Inhabitants:",
                    value: liste,
                    inline: false
                },
            )
            .setColor(`AQUA`)
            .setFooter(`Logic RP | ${versionNumber}`)
        channelStat.edit({embeds: [embed]})
    }).catch((error) => {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('The Server Is Currently Down')
            .setImage('https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/PaPGVPWBJVWcsboWGg9IWOfE0U0QSj1sb3UEwYIHYcA/https/images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/zcWeRc4OUGdU4UKejuGPzrBt2CvqZY8iIqPZtcrUc84/https/images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/QyWWFfOXuBL0VfdsZNJJdwoLQKQcvmpXo9IHRZoDM6U/https/cdn-longterm.mee6.xyz/plugins/reaction_roles/images/873023096611799080/911344681e6437aff9cc5e8a6660412e8733a43cde7dc38d01649a557a5e46d8.gif')
            .setColor('AQUA')
            .setFooter(`Logic RP | ${versionNumber}`)
        channelStat.edit({embeds: [embed]})
    });
    }, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I will use `channelStat` to get the channel messages.

Then, I'll use the `fetch` API to edit the `msg`, and add the response to it:

```js
const channelStat = client.channels.cache.get('902678733977157632').messages.fetch('902682557789908992').then((msg) => {
  msg.edit({embeds: [embed]});
});
```